# Extracting linked CSS files with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

Whats the best way to parse HTML and extract linked CSS files using PHP?

Comment: say what? im not sure what u want to do

Comment: In other words, get a web page with PHP cURL and then parse the string for all `<link href="/any.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) can probably help you out:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html'); // Can replace with $dom->loadHTML($str);

$link_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');

foreach($link_tags as $link_tag)
{
   // if $link_tag rel == stylesheet
   //   get href value and load CSS
}
```

Comment: I tried this. However if you try some urls, like www.google.com, you'll get an error:`Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag nobr invalid in Entity, line: 7`

Comment: DOMDocument's very picky about the html and will throw lots of warnings. This is one of the few places where supressing errors with '@' is acceptable, as there's no way to tell the underlying libraries to shut up.

Comment: @Andres, that's just a warning.  It happens that Google's home page isn't valid HTML.  (In fact, it's abusively incorrect HTML in order to get the file size as small as possible.)  You should still have gotten data from it.  Try calling `saveXML` on the resulting DOMDocument object.

Comment: @Marc, as a matter of fact [you can silence the warnings](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

Comment: How do we do this but turn it into an array instead of an object?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution using regular expressions.

```
$content = '...';

$n = preg_match_all('/"([^"]+?\.css)"/', $content, $matches);
if ($n !== FALSE && $n > 0) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use curl class to get the HTML file, then use the DOMDocument class to parse the HTML for CSS links. If you are looking for more, you will have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument http://it.php.net/domdocument

check in php documentation